# PHP: Does ini_set("memory_limit","1024M"); implicitly relase memory resources on PHP script execution end?

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

Upload Big files to EC2 Server,
my configuration are:

```
ini_set("display_errors",1);
ini_set("memory_limit","1024M");
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '500M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '5000M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

it's working fine

But will the **script automatically free all the resource associated** with it

or **Programmer should free resource explicitly**

What default(best) values a Programmer should set

Comment: it will free all resources once completed

Comment: ok, and what about if RAM at EC2 is 5GB and I am allocating 1GB upon file uploading. what you say if I set 128MB Memory in ini_set() which is better 1GB or 128MB ? so that server has enough memory and my files get uploaded without crashes. and in the above code what ini_set configurations should I use and should not use ?

Comment: There is max memory limit allocation for php. if you set -1 in memory limit it will use to max limit set for PHP. it will not exceed from that. This needs to be handle on server end beyond of PHP

Comment: But if you have set more then allowed memory for PHP then server will replace it with default memory from php.ini I think it is 128M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[ini_set](http://php.net/ini_set)**

> Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.

Need to say anything more? Yes one thing! Garbage collection has nothing to do with the `ini_set` calls that you have. Both are 2 different things.

Comment: ok, and what about if RAM at EC2 is 5GB and I am allocating 1GB upon file uploading. what you say if I set 128MB Memory in `ini_set()`
which is better 1GB or 128MB ? so that server has enough memory and my files get uploaded without crashes.
and in the above code what `ini_set` configurations should I use and should not use ?

Comment: A 1GB file upload doesn't require 1 GB ram for your script. And if you provide an upper limit to your script it does not mean that it will use all of it. Why would you let someone upload a 1GB file in the first place?

Comment: I've to upload multiple file i.e Images, Game APK, Videos etc.
and space on EC2 is running out so planning to move data to S3.

Comment: But that has nothing to do with ram

Answer (score 2):

It will free all resources once completed.
There is max memory limit allocation for php. if you set -1 in memory limit it will use to max limit set for PHP. it will not exceed from that. This needs to be handle on server end beyond of PHP
But if you have set more then allowed memory for PHP then server will replace it with default memory from php.ini I think it is 128M. To use MAX available memory for PHP ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'). This will allow you to use max available memory for PHP execution.

Answer (score 1):

The resources will be automatically freed when the script execution stops.

> What default(best) values a Programmer should set

There is no such thing. It depends on the actual memory usage...

Comment: what about if RAM at EC2 is 5GB and I am allocating 1GB upon file uploading. what you say if I set 128MB Memory in ini_set() which is better 1GB or 128MB ? so that server has enough memory and my files get uploaded without crashes. and in the above code what ini_set configurations should I use and should not use ?

Comment: @LukyBoy-KU You are allocating 1GB for the script. I have no idea what happens there.... If you create in memory an array of 2GB worth of data u need more (well, idiotic example). Anyway, depends of what you do INSIDE the script.

Comment: I am allocating 1G for file not script, as I've to upload some time files larger than 512MB. so please tell me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: ini_set("memory_limit","1024M"); -> you are allocating for the php script that may or may not include the upload and may or may not include processing